# Подготовленный запрос, динамический запрос EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linq, entity-framework-core

Как правильно реализовывается фильтрация данных в случаях большого количества разных параметров?
Например, я сейчас наделал вот таких костылей:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Start) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Finish))
{
    logs = await _context.Logs
    .Include(l => l.User)
    .Where(l => l.DateTimeInsert.Date == DateTime.Parse(filter.Start).Date).ToListAsync();
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Start) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Finish))
{
    logs = await _context.Logs
    .Include(l => l.User)
    .Where(l => l.DateTimeInsert >= DateTime.Parse(filter.Start) && l.DateTimeInsert <= DateTime.Parse(filter.Finish)).ToListAsync();
}
else
{
    logs = await _context.Logs
    .Include(l => l.User)
    .ToListAsync();
}  

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.UserLogin))
{
    logs = logs.Where(l => l.User.Email == filter.UserLogin).ToList();
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.UserName))
{
    logs = logs.Where(l => l.User.UserName == filter.UserName).ToList();
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.TransactionType))
{
    logs = logs.Where(l => l.TransactionTypes == filter.TransactionType).ToList();
}
```

Есть ли способ, подготовить данные для блока `where` и обратиться к контексту один раз перед вызовом `view`?

Comment: Можно, используй Expression<Func<T, bool>> и собирай (compose) через And или Or, а потом скармливай внутрь Where. Этих методов для склеивания Expression по-умолчанию нет, но можно найти [PredicateBuilder в инете](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: @SultanovShamil под каждый фильтр отдельный Expression<Func<T, bool>>, я правильно понял?

Comment: Их можно собрать все воедино в один Expression, а потом разом закинуть в Where.
Небольшой пример для [Or](https://github.com/mt89vein/HeadHunterClient/blob/138f9a3760c4b7586e9004ed904534ad7ac572d8/HeadHunter.Integration/Services/VacancyService.cs#L130)

Comment: @SultanovShamil Можете сделать ответ и дать пример пожалуйста, не имел дело ни разу с этим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя [predicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) можно переписать следующим образом:

```cs
// тоже самое что и Expression<Func<Log, bool>> predicate = l => true;
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Log>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Start) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Finish))
{
    predicate = predicate.And(l => l.DateTimeInsert.Date == DateTime.Parse(filter.Start).Date);
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Start) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Finish))
{
    predicate = predicate.And(l => l.DateTimeInsert >= DateTime.Parse(filter.Start) && l.DateTimeInsert <= DateTime.Parse(filter.Finish));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.UserLogin))
{
    predicate = predicate.And(l => l.User.Email == filter.UserLogin);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.UserName))
{
    predicate = predicate.And(l => l.User.UserName == filter.UserName);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.TransactionType))
{
    predicate = predicate.And(l => l.TransactionTypes == filter.TransactionType);
}

 logs = await _context.Logs
    .Include(l => l.User)
    .Where(predicate)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Т.о. сперва собираем всё условие, а потом разом передаем это условие в .Where()

Comment: Чего ругается на устаревшую запись, не обращать внимание?

Comment: Кто ругается? Какой текст? Я использую данный код в проде уже несколько лет, полет отличный

Answer (score 1):

В простых случаях можно обойтись тем, что вы создаёте "пустое" условие `.Where(x => true)` и добавляете условия по мере необходимости, как-то так:

```
public class Handler : BaseHandler, IRequestHandler<Query, Result>
{
    public Handler(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
        : base(applicationDbContext)
    {
    }

    public async Task<Result> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var query = this.ApplicationDbContext.Accounts.Where(x => true);

        query = ApplyFilters(query, request);

        //query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Title);

        var accounts = await query.Paging(request)
                                  .AsNoTracking()
                                  .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);

        return new Result(accounts.Select(x => new AccountDto(x)), await query.CountAsync(cancellationToken));
    }

    private static IQueryable<Account> ApplyFilters(IQueryable<Account> query, Query request)
    {
        if (request.IsCorrespondent != null)
            query = query.Where(x => x.IsCorrespondent == request.IsCorrespondent);

        if (!request.ShowInactive)
            query = query.Where(x => x.IsActive);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Needle))
            query = query.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(request.Needle) || x.Notes.Contains(request.Needle));

        return query;
    }
}
```

В более общем случае используйте predicate builder как указано в ответе @Sultanov Shamil, вот мой пример:

```
[UsedImplicitly]
public class Handler : BaseHandler, IRequestHandler<Query, IEnumerable<Contact>>
{
    public Handler(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
        : base(applicationDbContext)
    {
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<Contact>> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> expr = x => x.OwnerId == request.ManagerId;

        if (request.Filter.CityId != null)
        {
            Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> exprCity = x => x.ApplicationUser.CityId == request.Filter.CityId;
            expr = expr.AndAlso(exprCity);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Filter.SearchText))
        {
            Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> exprText = x => x.DisplayName.Contains(request.Filter.SearchText) || x.Notes.Contains(request.Filter.SearchText);
            expr = expr.AndAlso(exprText);
        }

        return this.GetAsync(expr, x => x.DisplayName);
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Contact>> GetAsync<TOrderKey>(Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<Contact, TOrderKey>> orderBy)
    {
        return await this.ApplicationDbContext.Contacts
                         .Include(x => x.ApplicationUser.City)
                         .Where(predicate)
                         .OrderBy(orderBy)
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем Where(t => true) ? можно просто .AsQueryable()

Comment: @SultanovShamil Это чисто привычка пришедшая из sql: я там так же пишу where 1 = 1 а потом только начинаю писать условия. Типа, проще комментировать. А поскольку я узнал sql раньше, чем c# и linq - некоторые вещи просто уже въелить в пальцы до автоматизма. А так вы правы: ваш вариант для C# семантичнее.

Comment: @AK Правильно ли я понимаю, что при использовании фильтров на первом примере в БД обращения не идут, а пойдут только тогда когда я обращусь к query?

Comment: @Winteriscoming правильно понимаете. Потому что там везде IQueryable, а не IEnumerable