# LinqToDB. Как я могу вставить условие между методов расширения Linq?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, entity-framework, linq

У меня есть вот такой большой запрос (скрин 1). А также много условий. Мне нужно вставить условие, при котором бы выполнялся метод расширения. К примеру у меня в коде много Where, я хочу чтобы некоторые из них выполнялись только при определенных условиях, эти условия довольно большие и в SQL не конвертируются. Пример:
у меня есть такой код:

```cs
var x = int.TryParse(model["maxPrice"].FirstOrDefault(), out int maxPrice);
```

нужно сделать так, чтоб если в результате я получил true, тогда добавить к выражению Linq

```cs
.Where(car => car.Price < maxPrice).
```

Это только один пример, таких в коде требуется несколько и на каждый формировать запрос как по мне не рациональною
Что посоветуете сделать?

Код:

```cs
allCars = _adverts.Cars
                    .Include(_ => _.Category)
                    .Include(_ => _.IdentityUser)
                    .Where(car => car.Price > minPrice)
                    .Where(car => car.Price < maxPrice)
                    .Where(_ => categories.Contains(_.Category.Id))
                    .OrderBy(_ => _.Id)
                    .Skip(index)
                    .Take(8)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Добавить в Where условие, например `.Where(x => x.Price > minPrice && x.Model == "Bently")`. И ловите минус в вопрос за то, что вставляете код картинкой, а не текстом. Не конвертируются -- значит, надо разобрать на конструкции, которые конвертируются, это возможно по двум направлениям: составление дерева выражений и DbFunctions. А вам стоит привести конкретный пример того, что не конвертируется. Без примера - вопрос дубликат для такого например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/785029/213987

Comment: У меня есть такой код: var x = int.TryParse(model["maxPrice"].FirstOrDefault(), out int maxPrice); Мне нужно сделать так, чтоб если в результате я получил true, тогда добавить к выражению Linq .Where(car => car.Price < maxPrice). Это только один пример, таких в коде требуется несколько и на каждый формировать запрос как по мне не рационально.

Comment: Ваш вопрос уже отвечен, больше примеров построения `Expression<Func>` можете посмотреть здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1024509/213987 или здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1227018/213987 и здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1111234/213987 В подобных случаях Where пишут ОДИН раз в виде `.Where(predicate)` а предикат поиска отдельным методом делают, конструируя Expression.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать ваш DbSet совместно с AsQueryable.
Разберем по пунктам:

1. Создаем метод-расширение для вашего DbSet;
2. Вызываем его и фильтруем данные как вам нужно (там же вы можете указать все Include и прочее.

1 пункт:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItems<T>(this DbSet<T> set, Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> function)
    where T : class
{
    var db = set.AsQueryable();
    db = function(db);
    var res = await db.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    return res;
}
```

2 пункт:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<Order>> FindOrdersAsync(FindOrdersArgs args)
{
    return dbContext.Orders.GetItems(x =>
    {
        if (args.Status != null)
        {
            x = x.Where(x => x.Status == args.Status.Value);
        }
        if (args.StartDate != null)
        {
            x = x.Where(x => x.StartDate.Date >= args.StartDate.Date);
        }
        
        return x.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Препочитаю строить Expression, но плюс - вполне заслужен.